# VLFeat "Name is nonexistent or not a director" error matlab

Tags: matlab, vlfeat

I tried to install VlFeat in matlab as mentioned in their website (https://www.vlfeat.org/install-matlab.html), but when I ran the `run('VLFEATROOT/toolbox/vl_setup')` command I get the following error

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
/VLFEATROOT/toolbox/mex/mexa64 
> In path (line 109)
In addpath (line 86)
In vl_setup (line 78)
In run (line 91)
```

please help me with this issue
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: "VLFEATROOT" is the location where you installed VLFEAT, substitute that name for the actual root location of vlfeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!
I got the above error after I ran the file downloaded from GitHub,
instead use this link to download the package(https://www.vlfeat.org/download/vlfeat-0.9.21-bin.tar.gz) extract it, and follow the installation procedure mentioned on their website.